# How to call randomForest predict for use with ROCR?

Tags: r, random-forest

I am having a hard time understanding how to build a ROC curve and now I came to the conclusion that maybe I don't create the model correctly. I am running a randomforest model in the dataset where the class attribute "y_n" is 0 or 1. I have divided the datasets as bank_training and bank_testing for the prediction purpose. 
Here are the steps i do:

```
bankrf <- randomForest(y_n~., data=bank_training, mtry=4, ntree=2,
                  keep.forest=TRUE, importance=TRUE)
bankrf.pred <- predict(bankrf, bank_testing, type='response',
                  predict.all=TRUE, norm.votes=TRUE)
```

Is it correct what I do till now? The bankrf.pred object that is created is a list object with 2 classes named: aggregate and individuals. I dont understand where did this 2 class names came out? Moreover when I run:

```
summary(bankrf.pred)
           Length Class  Mode     
aggregate  22606  factor numeric  
individual 45212  -none- character
```

What does this summary mean? The datasets (training & testing) are 22605 and 22606 long each. If someone can explain me what is happening I would be very grateful. I think there is something wrong in all this.

When I try to design the ROC curve with ROCR I use the following code:

```
library(ROCR)
pred <- prediction(bank_testing$y_n, bankrf.pred$c(0,1))

Error in is.data.frame(labels) : attempt to apply non-function
```

Is just a mistake in the way I try to create the ROC curve or is it from the beginning with randomForest?

Comment: The structure of `banrf.pred` is completely explained in the documentation in `?predict.randomForest`.

Comment: I've checked it and according to it, it should be ok like this, but I still am not able to plot a roc curve with ROCR and I think that there should be some problem with the model.

Comment: Well, your question contains no information about how you've tried to create a ROC curve or how exactly it hasn't worked, so it will be difficult for anyone to help with that piece.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the function you are attempting to use includes this description of its two main arguments:

> **predictions**    A vector, matrix, list, or data frame containing the
>   predictions.
>
> **labels**     A vector, matrix, list, or data frame containing the true
>   class labels. Must have the same dimensions as 'predictions'.

You are currently passing the variable `y_n` to the `predictions` argument, and what looks to me like nonsense to the `labels` argument.

The predictions will be stored in the output of the random forest model. As documented at `?predict.randomForest`, it will be a list with two components. `aggregate` will contain the predicted values for the entire forest, while `individual` will contain the predicted values for each individual tree.

So you probably want to do something like this:

```
predictions(bankrf.pred$aggregate, bank_testing$y_n)
```

See how that works? The *predicted* values are passed to the `predictions` argument, while the "labels" or true values, are passed to the `labels` argument.

Comment: Nope...it didn't work again. The error now is: Prediction format is invalid. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: @spektra Well, the answers you get will only be as good as the reproducibility of your question. Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: A factor is not a vector. You must convert each factor (predictions or labels) using as.numeric() first.

Comment: @CS Looks like the predictions can't be a factor, but the labels can (if you look at the code, the case of a factor is explicitly handled for the labels).

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for checking the code :)  I had the same mistake as the OP just now (I think) and fixed it with as.numeric().

Answer (score 0):

You should erase the `predict.all=TRUE` argument from `predict` if you simply want to get the predicted classes. By using `predict.all=TRUE` you are telling the function to keep the predictions of all trees rather than the prediction from the forest.